# Trouble simplifying this Trigonometric Identity

Tags: trigonometry

I am having trouble trying to solve this question:

$\cos \theta \cot\theta(\sec\theta - 2\tan\theta)$

I have had 2 different answers but not the right one.

It's supposed to be: $\cot\theta - 2\cos\theta$

but my skills are rusty and I am having trouble trying to determine exactly what to do. I keep simplifying the identities then multiplying the fractions but I am just super lost..

I am just looking for some help and guidance for this. Thank you.

Comment: $\cos\theta\sec\theta = 1$ and $\cot\theta\tan\theta = 1$...

Comment: The expression is $ab\left(\dfrac1a-\dfrac2b\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos  \theta \cot  \theta (\sec  \theta -2\tan  \theta )=\cos  \theta \frac { \cos { \theta  }  }{ \sin { \theta  }  } \left( \frac { 1 }{ \cos { \theta  }  } -\frac { 2\sin { \theta  }  }{ \cos { \theta  }  }  \right) =\\ =\frac { \cos ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  }{ \sin { \theta  }  } \frac { \left( 1-2\sin { \theta  }  \right)  }{ \cos { \theta  }  } =\frac { \cos { \theta  }  }{ \sin { \theta  }  } \left( 1-2\sin { \theta  }  \right) =\frac { \cos { \theta  } -2\sin { \theta \cos { \theta  }  }  }{ \sin { \theta  }  } =\frac { \cos { \theta  }  }{ \sin { \theta  }  } -\frac { 2\sin { \theta  } \cos { \theta  }  }{ \sin { \theta  }  } =\cot { \theta  } -2\cos { \theta  } $$

Comment: I am confused how $\frac { \cos ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  }{ \sin { \theta  }  } \frac { 1-2\sin { \theta  }  }{ \cos { \theta  }  }$  turns into $\frac { \cos { \theta  } -2\sin { \theta \cos { \theta  }  }  }{ \sin { \theta  }  } $ shouldn't it be $\frac { \cos { \theta  } -2\sin { \theta  }  }{ \sin { \theta  }  }$ since the $\cos^{2}{\theta}$ is divided by the bottom $\cos \theta$

Comment: @user3670552 $\cos^2\theta$ when divided by $\cos\theta$ is $\cos\theta$.

Comment: $cosx$ is reducted in the fraction

Comment: I know it is reduced when it is divided, but where does the $\cos \theta$ on the right of the $\sin \theta$ come from in the numerator.

Comment: @user3670552 Do you know that $a(b+c) = ab + ac$? Then $\cos\theta(1-2\sin\theta) = \cos\theta - 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$
\cos\theta\cot\theta(\sec\theta-2\tan\theta)=
\cot\theta\cos\theta\sec\theta-2\cos\theta\cot\theta\tan\theta=
\cot\theta-2\cos\theta
$$
because $\cos\theta\sec\theta=1$ and $\cot\theta\tan\theta=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\require {cancel}$
We have $$\cos \theta \cot \theta \ (\sec \theta - 2 \tan \theta)$$
Multiplying everything out (distributive property) we have$$\cot \theta \cos \theta \sec \theta - 2 \cos \theta \cot \theta \tan \theta$$
Note that $\cos \theta \sec \theta = 1$ and $\cot \theta \tan \theta = 1$, so these can cancel...
$$\cot \theta \cancelto {1}{\cos \theta \sec \theta} - 2 \cos \theta \cancelto {1}{\cot \theta \tan \theta}$$
And we're left with what we were looking for...$$\cot \theta - 2 \cos \theta$$